# Multiple Java Objects to single endpoint

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Instead of building a case statement for my Spring Boot Rest Controller, I want to have Spring use the correct endpoint. I am not even sure this is possible but I am hoping the universe could save me.

```
  @PostMapping("/endpoint")
    public String one(Greeting greet) {
        return "Greeting Posted";

    }

    @PostMapping("/endpoint")
    public String two(Address addr) {
        return "Address Posted";

    }
```

Current Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'RController' method 
public java.lang.String com.example.controller.RController.two(com.example.model.Address)
to {[/endpoint],methods=[POST]}: There is already 'RController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.example.controller.RController.one(com.example.model.Greeting) mapped.
```

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Please clarify. That doesn't make sense to me. They want one endpoint that can handle both types of payloads.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry for that. I would suggest taking a string as input(greeting, address) and initialize the respective class using a factory pattern approach

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Where would that String come from?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That string should come from the client.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Presumably, the `Address` is already coming from the client. How/where are they each included?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How about using a `@RequestParam` ?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Now we're getting somewhere. If they did use a request param, they could have two `@PostMapping` methods, where the annotation contains a `params` element differentiating between the two types.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, also if we can make that `params` mandatory ie. `required=true`, then we can avoid 2  `@PostMapping` methods and make it one and initialize the required class using Factory pattern and return the respective String as output

Comment: This is simply not how rest works ...

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. In some cases there will be Greeting and in others there will be and Address. The goal is to give one endpoint, one hole in the security firewall and be able to put the business logic in a front end application

Comment: @TimoReymann .. Does it help that the two request are coming at different times? And, yes, I know this is not how Rest works, but think about it, all middle-ware application could expose one catch all endpoint that can take different objects. Single point front-end with tightly coupled Java back-end.

Comment: @ahkar5 One option would be to choose type based on the content-type/accept header. Like application/vnd+company.BODYTYPENAME+json. This way you can map it based on Content-Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** possible. **It's ambiguous.**

As a good practice, if 2 resources will handle the data differently, you must create a different endpoint for each one.

Or possible workaround for you, it's create an ViewModel object and handle it in just one method.

```
public class GreetingAddressVM {

    private Address address;

    private Greeting greeting;

}
```

I'd prefer creating different mapping for each action.

Comment: Really, not possible? I would hope that in the future, this feature become possible.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that will be available, may cause confusion and will be pretty hard to maintain I guess